# How to automate updating of a setting on Cisco phones remotely?

Tags: cisco, voip

Normally, to make a change one would get the IP address of a Cisco VOIP phone, access its settings via a web browser and make any changes to the settings they need to using the web interface.

Is it possible to automate this process remotely if you have 10+ phones to take care of?

Comment: In CUCM you can use the Bulk Config options...is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Alternatively manage the settings through TFTP.